# Copying external Excel sheet to current workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, external

I'm working on small project in which I need to add sheets to the currently open workbook from any external database of worksheets in another workbook. I made a form to import any sheet that is required in the currently open (active) workbook.

The sheets will be copied from remote (in any other folder but same computer) workbook. I am using following code but due to unknown reasons the sheets are NOT getting copied to my current workbook.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim oWS      As String
Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook

FilePath = "D:\General Required Docs\DATA.xlsm"

If optFirst.Value = True Then
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   On Error Resume Next
   oWS = cboMaterial.Value
   Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
   wb.Worksheets(oWS).Copy      
   After:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
   activeWB.Activate
   wb.Close False

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Your macro adds a worksheet to wbk1, how can you paste on an existing worksheet of this workbook? i would also suggest adding wbk2.close at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
wb.Worksheets(oWS).Copy      
   After:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count)
```

to

```
wb.Worksheets(oWS).Copy      
   After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.count)
```

assuming that oWS is the index of the worksheet you want to copy.

Comment: Nice! didnt know this, thanks...is there any way to change the name ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Add_Bridge_1()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

    'add your own file path
    fileStr = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\HL DDS Templates.xlsx"

    Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(fileStr)

    'wbk2.Sheets("Bridge 1").Copy After:=Workbooks("WorkbookNameYouCopyCodeInto").Sheets(1)
    wbk2.Sheets("Sheet Name").Copy After:=wbk1.Sheets(1)
    wbk2.Saved = True
End Sub
```